# Zend vs Raw PHP

Tags: php

i'm still learning php but have a solid grasp on the basics and am starting work on actuall projects now, i'm wondering, in everyone's experience, is it better to use a framework, such as Zend, or to write all the code yourself.

Any opinion welcome :)

Comment: Way too generic - is it for a personal page or an amazon clone?

Comment: Learn the language before you start in on a framework. Otherwise you're trying to learn TWO things at the same time, and will probably just buried in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use a framework (or write your own) - you will end up reinventing wheels left and right.  You'll have alot of repeated code.   You'll lack good separation of your logic (model-view-controller is great in the case of web applications).  I strongly reccomend using a framework or choosing/writing components on your own..

Answer (score 1):

Begin your adventure with PHP frameworks from [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/).

The best frameworks for beginners.